# Disable cache sharing among websites

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

Is there a way to tell the browser not to share a cached resource among websites?
I want to give websites a link to some JavaScript on my server and I want to make the response be different for each domain using the Referer header as check.
The response which will be cached should be available to the domain that requested it and when the end users visit another site that uses the script link, another request should be made.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understand your question.

Does your scenario like: stackoverflow.com and yourwebsite.com use the same script called "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js", but you don't want to share the cached script with stackoverflow.com

**This is under the control of googleapis.com's web server.**

So if the cached resource's origin server(googleapis.com) want to implement the feature as you said, it may use the **Vary** response header. Vary Header define the secondary key of cache.

> Maybe "Vary: Origin" but only work for CORS
>
> Maybe "Vary: referer" but referer contains url path

It still doesn't solve your problem but I hope it helps.

see [MDN HTTP Cache Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#Varying_responses) and [RFC 7234 Section 4.1]